# Fastest temperature sensor for a bimetallic strip

Tags: sensor, temperature, delay, sampling

What is the best approach or sensor to analyze the temperature of a bimetallic strip?

From experimental data, the temperature swings due to a current flowing into the bimetal, are up to 80°C in a period of 20s which means 4°C/s.
I want to have a high sampling frequency (10Hz minimum, best would be 20-30Hz I guess).
Ultimately I must have high accuracy as well since I want to model the transient dynamics.

Edit: my goal is to have a batch of samples which contains the temperature transient (when the current is flowing) to make a model (for simulation/prediction). My need is to detect the temperature rising as soon as possible when the current is flowing (with no delays due to the kind of sensor being used, or at least to minimize it, in order to capture the dynamics of the physics as close as possible)

The current solution (an unknown thermocouple) has a sampling frequency of 10Hz and it has a variable delay up to 15samples, meaning it takes around 1.5s before detecting a rise in temperature when the current is flowing. My main problem is that I would like to detect the rise in temperature due to the current as soon as possible (closest to the physics).

Comment: Temperature does not change that quickly anyways. Why can't you just sample faster?

Comment: Your problem isn't the sensor. A thermocouple does not deliver samples but a continous voltage. You problem is most likely in the software which controls the A/D converter.

Comment: I'm not sure if the experiment setup is wrong but I believe the temperature does change that fast, the bimetallic strip is very thin and it was developed for this kind of application, the current flowing into it is up to 250A or more too.

Comment: What I mean is that relative to electronics, temperature does not change that quickly. You should be able to just sample faster. Also use as small a thermocouple as possible. I believe that a chopped pyroelectric sensor is one of the highest bandwidth methods, but I don't think you're anywhere near the sampling limit of a thermocouple.

Comment: The only thermocouple I used so far from National Instruments could sample up to 14Hz. I don't have the datasheet of the one being used and I can't access to it at the moment.

Comment: A thermocouple does not sample. There's some electronics and software which does that. You had to replace those.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I meant the "HW and SW" associated with the thermocouple would let me sample up to 14Hz. Thanks for your clarification

Comment: @Luca What's the range of temperature? What are you using the temperature knowledge for? How far away from the point of interest is the sensor to be placed? How many different measurement points will ever be developed? (Just 1? Or lots of them? If so, repeatability across instruments will be important.) You mentioned accuracy. Do you mean accuracy? Or Precision. if accuracy, you'll need traceability. (I helped develop a sensor reading 10 s/s, for example, with a range from -200 C to 450 C, no-calibration accuracy of 2 K and calibrated accuracy of 50 mK, and precision of 10 mK.)

Comment: @Luca  Does this sensor bend or change its shape as it is heated? Do you want to measure the amount of "change in shape" from this sensor?

Comment: The bimetals strip being monitored bends as it's heated and the thermocouple attached to its surface should follow the deflection. I don't think this is problematic though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get fast temperature measurements, you need two things:

- A fast temperature sensor
- Fast electronics

It shouldn't be too hard to get fast electronics. ADCs tend to have the speed advertised fairly clearly, and unless you mis-configure some kind of internal digital filter will not normally delay the data by more than one sample or so, so I'll talk about fast sensors.  A fast sensor needs:

- A low heat capacity
- A low thermal resistance link to the sample

Low heat capacity tends to mean small. A thermocouple would usually be a good choice. Make sure it is a bare junction, it should just look like two thin wires welded together. When I wanted good, small thermocouples I used to make my own from suitable wire, as commercial ones can have big blobs of metal or plastic covers which slow down the response time.

Low thermal resistance to the sample means short distance, and that distance filled with something with a high thermal conductivity. Welding directly to the bimetal strip would be best, solder would be next, followed by high quality conductive epoxy (e.g. Epotek H20E, not the stuff used for PCB repair). A non-electrically-conductive epoxy is not as good, so if you can set up your ADC so that it does not need to be electrically isolated from the bimetal strip that will help.

With a thermocouple formed by welding <100um diameter wire, welded onto a sample, I have been able to measure temperature changes into the low hundreds of Hz. There is a technique in Physics called "AC calorimetry" where this is commonplace, and you might find more useful information in papers on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

A bimetallic strip *is* a temperature sensor.  It changes geometry with a change in temperature.  If you need to know the temperature of the strip, you need a way to measure that geometry.

For a more specific answer, you need a more specific question, with much more information about what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I got the impression Luca wants to take the calibration data for that bimetal strip.

Comment: That seems reasonable, but I see no reason to guess at that.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my problem. I'd like to know if there is some other kind of temperature sensor which I could use to analyze a bimetallic strip temperature effects or some tricks/best approaches. Thanks for your clarification

Answer (score 0):

The thermal timeconstant of a cubic meter of silicon is 11,400 seconds, measured from one face of the cube to the opposite face.

The thermal timeconstant of 0.1meter cube of silicon is 100X faster, at 114 seconds.

The thermal timeconstantof 1cm cube of silicon is 100X faster, at 1.14 seconds.

The thermal timeconstant of 1mm cube of silicon is 100X faster, at 0.0114 seconds.

The thermal timeconstant of 100 micron cube of silicon is 100X faster, 0.000114 seconds or 114 microSeconds.

If you can get back-grinded diodes (which are about 100 micron thick) and install them on your bi-metallic strip, you'll have 114uS response, degraded by whatever thermal resistance the "installation material" interposes.

Or you can get a diode in SOT-23, with the die installed on the HEAT_REMOVAL metal tab, and just solder that to the bi-metallic strip. Given the thermal timeconstant of copper is a bit faster at 9,600 seconds per cubic meter, if you can achieve 1mm distance from the strip to the diode, you'll have 0.0114 second timeconstant.